# iMacros Javascript MouseEvent

Tags: javascript, html, imacros

how to detect 'You Win!' or 'You Lose!' content to implement different tasks.

Currently I'm using this method :

**Main.iim**

```
returncode = iimPlay("betwin.iim");
if (returncode == 1 ) {
min_submit(); //doing task 1
}

var returncode2 = iimPlay("betlose.iim");
if (returncode2 == 1 ){
double_submit(); //doing task 2             
}
```

**Betwin.iim**

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:win CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER
```

**Betlose.iim**

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:lose CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="result" class="center">
    <div id="win" class="bold center">You Win!</div>
    <div id="lose" class="bold center"></div>
</div>
```

Since the page always contain the two divs, so the betwin and betlose always true return 1. Is there anyway to detect the content of div tag ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="result" class="center">
    <div id="win" class="bold center">You Win!</div>
    <div id="lose" class="bold center"></div>
</div>
```

If I am correct in this case text that appears is You Win! So try to use these codes.

Betwin.iim

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:win&&:You<SP>Win* CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER
```

Betlose.iim

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:lose&&TXT:You<SP>Lose* CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER
```

Check is the Betlose.iim text `You Lose!`. If not try to use correct text.

Comment: Well it works perfectly, but if there is a text change in content. Let's say, You win (amount) ! The amount always change the text. Is there anyway to detect the only first two character ?

Comment: I edited the answer and added * to end of the text. That way if any character appears then the iMacros will register it.